# Why is an attenuator placed on the scope end and not the PCB end?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-voltage, impedance-matching, high-speed, attenuator

I've noticed when adding an external attenuator between PCB and the scope (1MOhm) that it is placed in this manner:

PCB -> SMA Socket -> **SMA Cable Plug -> SMA Attenuator** -> SMA-to-BNC -> Scope

Why is it bad practice to use:

PCB -> SMA Socket -> **SMA Attenuator -> SMA Cable Plug** -> SMA-to-BNC -> Scope

I assume this is due to an increase in reflection of the signal when putting the attenuator first.

When taking high voltage measurements (>400V; where limit of SMA is 400V) a 7/16 DIN connector is more ideal (limit 1400Vrms). Is it acceptable for the following to be used:

PCB -> 7/16 Socket -> **7/16 Attenuator** -> 7/16-to-N -> N-to-SMA -> **SMA Cable** -> **SMA Attenuator (0dB)** -> SMA-to-BNC -> Scope

Comment: Can you describe what kind of specific device you mean, are you sure you don't mean a terminator?

Comment: SMA Attenuator:
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rf-attenuators/2859545/

7/16 Attenuator:
http://www.e-meca.com/rf-attenuators/7-16-din/25-watt/635-3-11

Comment: If you put the attenuator first, the signal is attenuated and sent through the cable at a lower voltage level, so it can be more influenced by noise. Your noise floor will be higher.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I will be attenuating from 1000V to 100V so the noise floor won't be too much of an issue I don't think. I'm more concerned about timing characteristics during a switching event that can be impacted by impedance or reflection. Is this something I need to worry about with any of these setups?

Comment: What signal are you measuring? What is its frequency content? What is the source impedance?

Comment: I'm measuring the Vds output waveform of a MOSFET when it's switched on/off. Rise/fall time around 50ns and pulse width 500ns at 1Hz. I do not have source impedance info at hand right now.